# SQL loop to get next and before data

Tags: php

I'm doing a project that publishes news.

At the moment it goes like this I have an page called noticia_select.php ,

that prints all data from an selected news.

It also has "next news" and "older news" buttons.

Problem is that my uniq id is only for code identity for example:

```
first news:
id=1  
name=a 
content=b
```

Second news doesn't need to be id=2 it can be id=3 or 10 depends on deletes made by user.

How can I make an light loop to search the exact before news and next news searching by id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is two queries, `CURRENT_ID` is id of you selected news item.

Next news (element)

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id > CURRENT_ID ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Previous news (element):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id < CURRENT_ID ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: worked perfectly ty so mutch, i was thinking on loops like for or while when there was no need at all lol ty again